# amcharts4 - how to escape square bracket character ("[")

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I would like to have **Spread Value [EUR]** as my title axis text so I tried with

```js
valueAxis.title.text = "Spread Value \[EUR\]";
```

because

```js
valueAxis.title.text = "Spread Value [EUR]";
```

results in **Spread Value**.

Any suggestions how to fix?

Note: I could fix it with **Spread Value (EUR)** but I would like to use square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`valueAxis.title.html`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#html_property) instead of [`valueAxis.title.text`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#text_property):

```
valueAxis.title.html = "Spread Value [EUR]";
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdGzOJ) is an example code pen.

Alternatively you can use double `[[]]` with `valueAxis.title.text`:

```
valueAxis.title.text = "Spread Value [[EUR]]";
```

Comment: do you have by chance a recommendation for `series.name` as well?

Comment: @udo You can use `[[asdf]]`. I also updated my answer, because it works on `valueAxis.title.text` too.